# The Equation $F(x+y+z, x^2+y^2+z^2)=0 $ defines $z$ implicitly as a function of $x$ and $y$, say $z=f(x,y)$. Determine $ \partial f/ \partial x$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

The Equation $F(x+y+z, x^2+y^2+z^2)=0 $ defines $z$ implicitly as a function of $x$ and $y$, say $z=f(x,y)$. Determine $ \partial f/ \partial x$

**Attempt:**

Let $x+y+z=u_1, ~~x^2+y^2+z^2=u_2$

Then $F(u_1,u_2)=0$

Could someone guide me on how to take a step from here?

Thank you for reading through!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track. Carrying on from where you left off:
\begin{align*}
F(u_1,u_2) &=0 \\
\frac{\partial F(u_1,u_2)}{\partial u_1}\frac{\partial u_1}{\partial x}
+ \frac{\partial F(u_1,u_2)}{\partial u_2}\frac{\partial u_2}{\partial x} &=0 \\
\frac{\partial F(u_1,u_2)}{\partial u_1}\left(1+\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}\right)
+ \frac{\partial F(u_1,u_2)}{\partial u_2}\left(2x+2f(x,y)\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}\right) &=0 \\
\end{align*}

> Rearranging, $\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x} = -\frac{\frac{\partial F(u_1,u_2)}{\partial u_1}+2x\frac{\partial F(u_1,u_2)}{\partial u_2}}{\frac{\partial F(u_1,u_2)}{\partial u_1}+ 2z\frac{\partial F(u_1,u_2)}{\partial u_2}} $

Comment: Ohh!! Thank you. I think the mistake which I always commit is to treat $z$ as an independent variable, as in step $2$. Would you be able to tell me , when is $z$ treated as an independent variable and when it's not ( when partially differentiating w.r.t $x$ or $y$.

Comment: In this case I know $z=f(x,y)$ so I know $z$ is a function of $x$ and $y$ so once $x$ and $y$ are chosen $z$ is fixed.